# Slick.js carousel inside a parent carousel is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I am trying to create a carousel. There will be a carousel inside the main carousel. The problem is When I created the carousel, The first carousel is working fine. But the second carousel is not loading the child carousel.

This is the first carousel and I am looking like this carousel.
[This is the first carousel and It's working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYIxt.png)

But when I go to the next carousel. Then the right side carousel is not working.
[This is the image that is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohi0n.jpg)

I am trying to create a Elementor Widget with Repeater field. This is the codes.

````
  function product_lisi_slide( ) {

        $args = wp_parse_args( array(
            'post_type'   => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ) );
    
        $query_query = get_posts( $args );
    
        $dropdown_array = array();
        if ( $query_query ) {
            foreach ( $query_query as $query ) {
                $dropdown_array[ $query->ID ] = $query->post_title;
            }
        }
    
        return $dropdown_array;
    }


class nancy_slider_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {


    public function get_name() {
        return 'nancy_slider';
    }

    
    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'Nancy Slider', 'plugin-name' );
    }

    
    public function get_icon() {
        return 'fa fa-code';
    }

    
    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'general' ];
    }

    
    protected function _register_controls() {

        $this->start_controls_section(
            'slide_section',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'plugin-name' ),
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
            ]
        );




$repeater = new \Elementor\Repeater();


          $repeater->add_control(
            'background', [
                'label' => __( 'Image', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::MEDIA,
                'label_block' => true,
            ]
        );

         $repeater->add_control(
            'select_product',
            [
                'label'       => esc_html__( 'Select Product', 'Profits11' ),
                'type'        => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
                'multiple' => true,
                'options'     =>product_lisi_slide(),                           
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'lists',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Repeater List', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
                'fields' => $repeater->get_controls(),
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();


    }




    
    protected function render() {

        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

         $dynamicid = rand(13254343, 4664567);
         $mini_dynamicid = rand(13254343, 46645767);

        foreach($settings['lists'] as $list){
             $q = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type'      => 'product',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,  
                            'post__in' => $list['select_product'],
                   ));
        }


           echo'<script>
                     jQuery(window).load(function($){
                          jQuery("#snacy-'.$dynamicid.'").slick({
                              dots: true,
                              infinite: true,
                              speed: 500,
                              fade: true,
                              slidesToShow: 1,
                              nextArrow: "<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-right\"></i>",
                              prevArrow: "<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left\"></i>",
                            });

                            jQuery("#active-mini-'.$mini_dynamicid.'").slick({
                              dots: true,
                              infinite: true,
                              speed: 500,
                              fade: true,
                              arrows: false,
                              slidesToShow: 1,
                            });
                        });

                         elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction( "frontend/element_ready/widget", function( $scope ) {
                             jQuery("#snacy-'.$dynamicid.'").slick({
                                  dots: true,
                                  infinite: true,
                                  speed: 500,
                                  fade: true,
                                  slidesToShow: 1,
                                  nextArrow: "<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-right\"></i>",
                                  prevArrow: "<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left\"></i>",
                                });

                            })
                 </script>';


                 echo'<script>
                       jQuery(window).load(function($){
          
                            jQuery("#active-mini-'.$mini_dynamicid.'").slick({
                              dots: true,
                              infinite: true,
                              speed: 500,
                              fade: true,
                              arrows: false,
                              slidesToShow: 1,
                            });
                        });
                 </script>';


                $html='<div class="nancy_slider" id="snacy-'.$dynamicid.'">';

                  foreach($settings['lists'] as $slide){

                       


                    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($slide['background']['id'],'large');
                    $html.='<div class="single_slider">
                          <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <img src="'.$image_url.'" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="mini_slide" id="active-mini-'.$mini_dynamicid.'">';
                                     while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
                                         $idd = get_the_ID(); 
                                        $html.='<div class="single_mini_slide">
                                               '.get_the_post_thumbnail().'
                                                '.get_the_title().'
                                           </div>';
                                      endwhile;
                                    $html.='</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>';
                  }
                      
                     

                $html.='</div>';


                echo $html;
        
                 
             }

           }```
````

Comment: You need to add the code to a working example, which shows the behavior. Screenshot images won't work

Comment: I am not able to do this. Can you please check the code?

Comment: No, that's not possible. We need  a working example. You might want to add your Example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) and link to it

Comment: Ok I will try it.

Comment: @yunzen Adding a link to Codepen is fine, but only when the code is *also* included directly in the question. Using third-party links only is discouraged, because the content of the link can be removed or changed, which would mean the question is no longer helpful to other users.

Comment: @Fluffy I know, but this is a newbie asker. I'd concert the codepen to a SO snippet, if we had any.

Comment: @yunzen Newbies still need to know how to use the website properly, because not everyone is as willing as you to help them edit their question to add their code :) If they are still asking poor quality questions when they're no longer a newbie, they don't get the benefit of the doubt anymore and won't understand why they have started getting downvotes for the same type of question they always asked. I suggest if you are offering to do this, you might mention to them what they should be doing themselves so at least they understand for future questions :)

Comment: @Fluffy I decide on the freaking that I have of the asker. Sometimes I present them the rules and sometimes I think it's better for them to learn by example.

Comment: @yunzen "*I decide on the freaking...*" ?? Not sure what that was meant to mean (is it a typo?), but either way there are guidelines for SO that everyone is meant to abide by, newbies included.Unfortunately a lot of them don't seem to realise this.

Comment: *feeling (bl**dy correction)

Comment: I think Custom Elementor Widget code is not working on Codepen.